# Scaling only one values in an array of objects in Javascript using d3.scale.linear

Tags: javascript, d3.js

What would be the best way to scale only the value in myData from 10 to 100 in the following data

```
myData = [
    {"name": "Alex", "value": 10}, 
    {"name": "Bob", "value": 110}, 
    {"name": "Raja", "value": 140}, 
];
```

Currently I am using  information from http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/scales and then scaling value in the following manner

```
var valueScale = d3.scale.linear()
                 .domain([0, d3.max(myArray, function(d) { return d.value} )])
                 .range([10, 100]);
```

but how to I use valueScale on myData so that the structure remains intact but the value only scales.

This is what my output data should look like
    myData = [
        {"name": "Alex", "value": 10}, 
        {"name": "Bob", "value": 79}, 
        {"name": "Raja", "value": 100}, 
    ];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to modify each Object in place:

```
myData.forEach(function(d){
    d.value = valueScale(d.value);
});
```

Note however, that this will produce the following output:

```
myData = [{"name":"Alex","value":16.42857142857143},
          {"name":"Bob","value":80.71428571428571},
          {"name":"Raja","value":100}]
```

because you are setting the `domain` of `valueScale` to start at 0, while the minimum `value` is 10. If you   want the modified Objects to match the output in your question, change the `domain` to match the maximum *and* minimum of your values:

```
.domain(d3.extent(myData, function(d) { return d.value} ))
```

Comment: That sure helped. Is there a similar function to assign the result to a different variable, leaving the original unchanged. foo = myData.forEach(...) does not seem to work :)